# Azure AD Identity.Client Calling AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword, get 406 error

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory

**UPDATE: I went back to Azure AD and created a new user. Carefully copied the new username and password and the code works. I previously used the username (email) and password of the user who created the directory and that threw an 406, not sure why?**

I downloaded the Azure up-console code. I followed the ReadMe file which is the following

When the console comes up, Here is what I type 
username: email used to log into Azure Portal
password: pw used to log into Azure Portal

In the sample code, the following code gets called

```
private async Task<AuthenticationResult> GetTokenForWebApiUsingUsernamePasswordAsync(IEnumerable<string> scopes, string username, SecureString password)
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = null;

                result = await App.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, username, password)
                    .ExecuteAsync();

            return result;
}
```

In the json file, I have the following settings

```
{
  "Authentication": {
    // Azure Cloud instance among:
    // - AzurePublic (see https://aka.ms/aaddevv2). This is the default value
    // - AzureUsGovernment (see https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-government/documentation-government-developer-guide)
    // - AzureChina (see https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/china/china-get-started-developer-guide)
    // - AzureGermany (See https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/germany/germany-developer-guide)
    "AzureCloudInstance": "AzurePublic",

    // Azure AD Audience among:
    // - AzureAdMyOrg (single tenant: you need to also provide the TenantId
    // - AzureAdMultipleOrgs (multi-tenant): Any work and school accounts
    // - AzureAdAndPersonalMicrosoftAccount (any work and school account or Microsoft personal account)
    // - PersonalMicrosoftAccount (Microsoft personal account only)
    "AadAuthorityAudience": "AzureAdMyOrg",


    "ClientId": "copied from azure ad client id",

    "TenantId": "copied from azure ad tenant id",

    "Tenant": "copied from azure ad tenant id"
  },
```

Register the client app (up-console)

1. In **App registrations (Preview)** page, select **New registration**.
2. When the **Register an application page** appears, enter your application's registration information:

   - In the **Name** section, enter a meaningful application name that will be displayed to users of the app, for example `up-console`.
   - In the **Supported account types** section, select **Accounts in any organizational directory**.

     > Note that if there are more than one redirect URIs, you'd need to add them from the **Authentication** tab later after the app has been created succesfully.
3. Select **Register** to create the application.
4. On the app **Overview** page, find the **Application (client) ID** value and record it for later. You'll need it to configure the Visual Studio configuration file for this project.
5. In the list of pages for the app, select **Manifest**, and:

   - In the manifest editor, set the `allowPublicClient` property to **true**
   - Select **Save** in the bar above the manifest editor.
6. In the list of pages for the app, select **API permissions**

   - Click the **Add a permission** button and then,
   - Ensure that the **Microsoft APIs** tab is selected
   - In the *Commonly used Microsoft APIs* section, click on **Microsoft Graph**
   - In the **Delegated permissions** section, ensure that the right permissions are checked: **User.Read**, **User.ReadBasic.All**. Use the search box if necessary.
   - Select the **Add permissions** button
7. At this stage permissions are assigned correctly but the client app does not allow interaction. 
   Therefore no consent can be presented via a UI and accepted to use the service app. 
   Click the **Grant/revoke admin consent for {tenant}** button, and then select **Yes** when you are asked if you want to grant consent for the
   requested permissions for all account in the tenant.
   You need to be an Azure AD tenant admin to do this.

#### Step 3:  Configure the sample to use your Azure AD tenant

In the steps below, "ClientID" is the same as "Application ID" or "AppId".

Open the solution in Visual Studio to configure the projects

Configure the client project

> Note: if you used the setup scripts, the changes below will have been applied for you

1. Open the `up-console\appsettings.json` file
2. Find the app key `ClientId` and replace the existing value with the application ID (clientId) of the `up-console` application copied from the Azure portal.
3. (Optionally) Find the line where `Tenant` is set and replace the existing value with your tenant ID.

#### Step 4: Run the sample

Clean the solution, rebuild the solution, and start it in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I went back to Azure AD and created a new user. Carefully copied the new username and password and the code works. I previously used the username (email) and password of the user who created the directory and that threw an 406, not sure why?